# Show the category and the list of all subcategories in wordpress sidebar of a post

Tags: wordpress

Lets say that I have a wordpress theme with 2 columns.
The left column its used as sidebar and in right I have the content.

What I want to do is something like this:

When I am in an article, in the sidebar I want to display the category for my article AND I want to display all the subcategories that I have in that category.

Example:

`Category A >
    - Subcategory A1
    - Subcategory A2`

`Category B >
 - Subcategory B1
 - Subcategory B2`

I`m in an article published in Category A with Subcategory A2

I want in sidebar to display all the information from the Category A, and in sidebar to be something like this:

`Category A >
 - Subcategory A1
 - Subcategory A2`

Answer (score 0):

```
$q_cat = get_query_var('cat');
$cat = get_category($q_cat);
$catname = $cat->cat_name;

echo $catname;
$childcategories = get_categories('child_of='.$cat->cat_ID);
foreach($childcategories as $ccat){
echo $ccat->cat_name;
```

or no echo try with

```
$output =''; <-- your html code
return $output;
```